# Does summation nth root of n -1 converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does this series converge or diverge :
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sqrt[n]n -1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series diverges by the limit comparison test since

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^{1/n} - 1}{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} n(n^{1/n} - 1) =\infty.$$

We have $n^{1/n} > 1$ and $n^{1/n} = 1 + a_n$ with $a_n > 0$.

Hence,

$$n = (1 + a_n)^n\\  \implies \ln n = n \ln(1 + a_n) < na_n \\ \implies n(n^{1/n} -1 ) = n a_n  > \ln n \to \infty.$$

Answer (score 9):

**Hint**. One may observe that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\sqrt[n]n -1=e^{\frac{\ln n}n}-1\ge\frac{\ln n}n\ge\frac{1}n.
$$