# Is the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\sqrt[k]{k}-1)$ divergent or convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I find this series to be a bit troublesum. I can't find a proper method that works. Root test doen't seem to be useful. Ratiotest got ugly. Integral test seems to force me to integrate a function $x^{1/x},$ which doesn't have any elementary primitive.

I can't find an apropriate limit to compare it to and do a limit test comparison.

Comment: WolframAlpha says that the serie diverges: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28k%5E%281%2Fk%29+-+1%29+from+k%3D1+to+inf Comparison test seems useful

Answer (score 7):

We have $$k^{1/k} -1= e^{\frac{\ln(k)}{k}}-1 >\frac{\ln(k)}{k},$$ so by comparison, the sum diverges.

Comment: How do you know that last inequality?

Comment: Taylor expansion of the exponential

Comment: For all $x \neq 0$ you have $e^x-1-x \ge 0$ with equality only at $x=0$. You can prove it using derivatives.

Answer (score 4):

As $k \to \infty$, one has
$$
\sqrt[k]{k}-1=\frac{\ln k}k+O\left(\frac{\ln^2 k}{k^2} \right)
$$ the given series is divergent, being the sum a divergent series and a convergent one.

Comment: I don't see how you expanded it that way?

Comment: @Parseval Using $$\sqrt[k]{k}=e^{\frac{\ln k}k}$$ and $e^x=1+x+O(x^2)$, as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Actually you answered an identical question before: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2160546/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Ok I see...